# Redirect directory but exclude a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-s3

So we have a wordpress site where we are using a plugin to push all files in the wp-content/uploads directory to Amazon S3. However, we use a video plugin which requires the use of the uploads directory in a temp folder to generate video thumbnails.

Due to the fact that we have a rewrite rule (as seen below) to redirect /wp-content/uploads to the relevant S3 address which is vital to get the backend functioning correctly, it is causing problems with the temp folders.

```
RedirectPermanent /wp-content/uploads/ [amazonbucketurl]/wp-content/uploads/
```

What we need is a redirect rule which can go in the .htaccess file and exclude /wp-content/uploads/thumb_tmp from the blanket redirect rule for /wp-content/uploads.

Any help will be great!

Comment: Does your video plugin run server-side to generate thumbnails? If so, you shouldn't need to worry about Apache settings because it shouldn't be making web requests to Apache - it should be Local OS filesystem access and is of course not subject to .htaccess rules. I may be mistaken though, have you tried it or are you anticipating that there may be problems?

Comment: Im not sure. I assume that it uses the apache web engine to parse the commands. I just need a solution to this redirect problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RedirectPermanent /wp-content/uploads/(?!thumb_tmp).* [amazonbucketurl]/wp-content/uploads/
```

Here `(?!thumb_tmp)` is used to exclude `thumb_tmp` sub folder from rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/uploads/thumb_tmp/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/uploads/thumb_tmp$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://dingvideo-europe-array.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works by running the rewrite rule on the uploads folder but excluding the thumb_tmp directory.